# Где здесь ошибка? Не могу понять!

Tags: c++

[image: моя работа]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <clocale>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    float a = 0.5, b = 2.9, x = 0.3;
    U = (pow(a, 3) + exp(-x) * cos(b * x)) / (b * x - exp(-x) sin(b * x) + 1);
    cout << U;
    return 0;
}
```

в чем проблема???

Comment: а где определение переменной `U`?

Comment: По-моему, компилятор дал исчерпывающее их перечисление, нет?

Comment: не, компилятор не все сказал,  ещё ошибки в 3,4 и 6 строке

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, компилятор дал исчерпывающее их перечисление... См. комментарии.

```
U = // Что это за переменная? где указан ее тип?
(pow(a, 3) + exp(-x) * cos(b * x)) / (b * x - 
exp(-x) sin(b * x)  // Какой знак должен быть между exp(-x) и sin(b * x) ?
 + 1);
```